# Serial upvoting reversed

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes, serial-voting

When today I logged in to my account and my reputation is down, I check what is the reason then it shows like this:

> Serial upvoting reversed

What does that mean?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We have [various systems](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) in place to detect targeted voting - that is to say, votes clearly aimed at *an individual user* rather than at individual posts. If you have a fan, friend, co-worker, or [sockpuppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685) that repeatedly sends votes your way, it's likely they'll sooner or later be invalidated and any reputation you might have gained from them will be forfeit as a result.

To avoid this, make sure you're not doing anything that would cause votes to be sent your way for reasons other than someone finding a post you wrote *useful*. In particular, let your friends know not to follow you around up-voting everything you write - and of course, don't do that to them either.

#### See: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Currently there is no way to stop anyone who is serial upvoting me from not doing it because the system does not provide me with an information who it is. It might be someone who is trolling me, which I have some suspicions about. Is it possible to tell a moderator or to check who is doing it? If not, why not?

Comment: Moderators can see who is involved and take action as needed.

Comment: So if I want to serially upvote someone, can I serially *down*vote them to get the required affect? :)