# Will serial upvoting / downvoting on Meta Stack Overflow be reversed?

Tags: support, meta, serial-voting

I am well aware of [serial upvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252087/3622940) being [reversed on the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/), but what about on this meta site?

As [voting is different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/3622940) and is to express opinions, I feel that there should be a difference, but it was not documented in the official meta documentation, [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917/3622940)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The serial voting script does run on child meta sites, yes.

See [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters) for example, where votes on a child meta were reversed. It is also [implicitly confirmed by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224874):

> The scripts run on **all sites**.

Emphasis mine; no exception for child meta sites made.

Comment: A more interesting question would have been 'Why does anyone even bother with voting fraud on meta?

Comment: @MartinJames: badges?

Comment: @MartinJames: [because some "children" get angry about objective comments from others, and that is how they express their frustration.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271332/will-serial-upvoting-downvoting-on-meta-stack-overflow-be-reversed?cb=1). There are also other reasons, but that is a common one. I do not buy the badges argument by any means since for that, they could just vote the latest and upcoming posts away rather than serial on someone's record. I also think that it is quite rare that someone would care so much about badges on meta.

Comment: @lpapp: it was just a guess. Why and how people vote is always personal. Votes on Meta are largely meaningless anyway. For example, the downvote on this answer is entirely meaningless, certainly without a motivating comment. What, exactly, would be wrong about the answer? Is there counter proof that the script *doesn't* run on Meta?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know, I just replied to your guess why I think it is not a common case for this. I do not understand the downvote for your helping post either... I personally upvoted it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is funny that you regard votes as meaningless as soon as you don't get rep for them :)

Comment: @usr: On *Meta* votes are largely meaningless other than to rank posts relative to one another; but in the context of serial voting it appears that people still care.

Comment: TL;DR version of @lpapp's comment:  Badges??  We don't need no stinking badges!