# Bulk of downvotes on most of my questions

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

Just an hour ago, I noticed a lot of downvotes on questions and answers of mine, some even being like three years old.

[image]

While I am not shedding any tears over the rep points lost, I am just wondering what can be the cause of that? Is this just some embittered user I somehow made angry or can this be something automatic (due to closure of user accounts)?

Comment: [Will serial upvoting / downvoting on Meta Stack Overflow be reversed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271332/will-serial-upvoting-downvoting-on-meta-stack-overflow-be-reversed)

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't have the correct terms for finding these answers. Should I delete my question or just marking as duplicate?