# Serial upvoting reversed but the rest of the upvotes for the day were not included

Tags: support

I see that serial up-voting will be reversed as mentioned in this answer [Serial upvoting reversed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252087/serial-upvoting-reversed)

But Isn't the right way to handle this is

If the serial voting is revered rest of the upvotes(valid ones) needs to be added as back? I mean the scenario is

1. Before the serial upvote I had 8 upvotes for the day
2. After serail upvote my upvote went to 20 upvotes a day and the max limit was reached
3. Now there was another answer which I did and got around 55points (4 upvotes)

Isn't the right way to handle this scenario is after reversing the serial upvote the rest of the valid upvotes needs to be added back??

Comment: Valid votes aren't reversed. Perhaps the votes you thought were valid, weren't?

Comment: @Yannis No .. This is the case where the limit for the day was reached because of the serial upvotes and later I had upvotes which anyways doesn't count for the day. But since there is a tool which runs at the end of the day and reverse any serial votes .. The tool doesn't take into account the valid upvotes after the serial upvotes .. Which I think should be handled properly by adding is back

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression the rep cap was recalculated after the script run, perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: @Yannis Yes I am pretty sure

Comment: Shouldn't a reputation recalc fix this? If that still exists....

Comment: Looking at the timestamps of the votes that you "lost" due to the rep cap, most of those look like they could have been part of the serial voting.  Maybe there is nothing to add back once the serial votes were reversed.  What do you see when you look at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Comment: @psubsee2003 See on 2/16/2015 I had 230 and there was 120 points because of serial upvoting...Now on 2/17/2015 The first msg I see is `-120` which is good as the serial votes were reversed but on 2/16/2015 there was additional 4 votes which were not included as the limit was reached and was not added back.. and also the valid vote in the serial vote was also not added back..

Comment: @Gopi I'm just working by what I see in your profile.  I see 15 votes in which you did not get a +10 on 2/16.  However, every single one of them looks like it *could* have been part of the serial voting, meaning those votes could have been reversed as well.

Comment: @psubsee2003 You might be right I remember seeing something like what I have explained anyways thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer your question, yes, reputation *should* be recalculated after any serial voting is reversed.  If it wasn't it certainly could be a bug, however, in your case, it may be accurate (but since I can't see anything beyond your public profile, I am only guessing).

If you look at your public reputation for the day in question, there are 23 upvotes that look suspicious given their time stamps.  9 are within 2 minutes of each other and the other 14 are within 2 minutes of each other (but about 8 minutes after the initial 9).  But you only show reputation for 8 of the original 9 votes.  The remaining 15 votes were not scored.

It is entirely possible that after the serial voting was reversed, there were no unawarded votes left, so when your reputation was recalculated, you didn't pick up anything else.

> [image: profile reputation feed screen shot]

---

Part of the confusion is probably because you are trying to audit your reputation via the reputation feed in your profile.  This is not an ideal way to do it. The profile reputation tab does its best to track reputation **events** based on when you see the impact to your score, so doesn't always look clean, especially in cases when there is serial voting.  If you really want to see what your specific reputation was for a given day, you are best looking at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.  There you will see every **valid** vote, and the specific posts that you earned reputation on a given day, and which votes were lost due to the rep cap.  Since the serial votes were reversed, you should not see them on that page anymore.