# Reputation got stuck on 990?

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-limit

I am regular user of SO site, [My StackOverflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3682162/vikrant)... very much interested in answering questions regarding my knowledge area. I noticed that, I've reached 990 reputation today.
Some users have upvoted my answer but anyhow it's not increasing after it! :(

I don't know what wrong I've done! Apologize, if a wrong question is being asked!

Comment: You know that there's a daily maximum of 200 rep you can gain?

Comment: oh alright then! but what about upvotes that are received after that? are they going to be added after a day?

Comment: @Vikrant No You have them, but you don't get reputation for them

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: @Vikrant Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation Also "reputation got stuck" what would John Skeet say: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation

Comment: see also: [Serial upvoting reversed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252087/serial-upvoting-reversed)

Comment: why on earth is this polite question -18 downvoted? what a hostile place

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't earn more than 200 rep with upvotes in one day.

Perhaps also a good time to remind you that you cannot vote on your own posts.  Fraud like this gets reliably detected by the system and all votes will be undone.  Tomorrow you'll be back at ~790.  You'll have to bide your time getting to a thousand, it requires votes from *other* SO users that find your posts helpful.  Not your friends either.  This should be self-evident.

Comment: how can you say that I myself upvoted my posts!

Comment: Saying it isn't very difficult.  Seeing it not either.  Denying it when it is so blatantly obvious is an odd cultural thing I don't otherwise understand.  Does that every really work in your neck of the woods?

Comment: oh yes! I got it now, my pair of friends only upvoted my all posts ... LOL!! is there any way to rollback them by myself or anywhre I can place request for that! before system does that?

Comment: @Vikrant their upvotes will be [automatically reverted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252090/839601) in a few hours

Comment: That's another cultural aspect I completely don't understand.  Your fraud was revealed and now you expect help to cover it up?  Does that ever really work in your neck of the woods?  Educate us please.

Comment: @HansPassant it makes us take a breath of relief. due to this kind of rules. but is there any limit on reputation you earn from giving correct answer ?

Comment: Just the daily rep cap.  A post [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/17034) still earns the poster ~150 rep every day after 3 years.  Not common of course.