# Serial upvoting?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I received 5 upvotes in quick fire succession for 5 consecutive recent posts. Rather abnormal activity for my tags at the best of times let alone over a weekend

I don't want bogus rep on my profile.

[image]

Comment: Thx. I had thought that five post upvotes may not be enough to trigger the reversal - will keep an eye out.

Comment: Hey . pass me them i don't mind having them xD.

Comment: @brettdj Even if it weren't, the solution isn't to post a public thread on meta.

Comment: Fair enough - I regret the meta posts.

Comment: Let's say I notice an interesting-looking user who gave a good answer, and so I decide to check out his other answers, many of which are good, and so I upvote them. Why is that considered "serial upvoting" and why is that considered bad or something which should be reversed?

Comment: @torazaburo you're supposed to vote on the posts you run into *naturally*  not because you traverse all posts from a single user. You don't want to know how many *friends* and *colleagues* vote on each others posts on a daily basis. The reputation gained by that practice no longer reflects trust but reflects the number of people you know or know you. That is relevant on Facebook not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rene I have no idea why you would say it's bad to upvote posts I run into when traversing all posts from a single user. Where did this "supposed to" come from? Who says? Traversing posts from a top user is a great way to browse the site. In what sense is it not "natural"? it certainly beats slogging through the swamp of the front page.

Comment: @torazaburo do what ever suits you but it is impossible to distinguish serial votes from users that want to do evil things and your well intended voting, that is all. Let's not make  a big deal out of this ...

Comment: Clearly the up-votes weren't treated as suspicious by the script. They remain intact. As do the swarthe of downvotes I have received from a now deleted account. Which probably washes in the end.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, nor does any moderator need to do anything.

The [serial voting detection script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252087/serial-upvoting-reversed) runs at 03:00 UTC and will reverse any votes that it considers to be serial. In your profile on your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641067/brettdj?tab=reputation) you'll see

> Voting corrected

which will correct the votes that the script deems invalid. The exact conditions are private but from 3 votes up or down in quick succession you might see a reversal of votes. If some of the serial votes (both up and down) aren't removed after the script ran, then you can raise a custom moderator flag, as stated in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252271/812149).

Keep in mind that, except the temporary fluctuations in your reputation, there is no permanent harm done.

Comment: _no permanent harm done_ in most cases. Rare cases with tag badges being revoked might happen or loss of privileges, etc... Most would likely be temporary if the user is an active participant on the site.

Comment: You shouldn't have had the badge or the privilege in the first place ....